# Can an sequence $(a_n)$ exist such that $\lim|na_n|=+\infty$, $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can an sequence $(a_n)$ having properties below exist?

1. $\lim|na_n|=+\infty$
2. $\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ is bounded for all $n$.

I don't think this sequence exists but I can't prove.

Is this possible to prove? Or are there any counter examples?

(Really sorry for the math symbols. It's a little bit difficult to type for me ;,|)

Comment: Try $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: Or $a_n=(-1)^n$. (In fact, *which* sequences did you try?)

Comment: If $a_n>0$ for all $n$, then it is not possible.

Comment: How genius!! Thanks!!

Comment: Actually the question came to mind while I was trying to solve such a problem that "can one use the Dirichlet's criterion for series to determine whether 1-1/2-1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6+1/7- ••• is convergent?"

Comment: So I tried to find sequences a_n, b_n such that lim a_n=0, a_n is decreasing, partial sum sigma b_n is bounded and finally (a_n×b_n) is (1, -1/2, -1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, •••)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for instance $a_n=(-1)^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Then you get

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\vert na_n\vert=\lim_{n\to \infty}\vert n(-1)^n\vert=\lim_{n\to \infty}n=+\infty.$$

And

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\in\{0,1\}$$

so it is bounded (though it does not converge !).

Comment: Thanks for the simple, perfect answer!